# Laplace Equations with Neumann boudary-value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

The problem is that, Assume U is connected, use the maximum principle to show that the only smooth solutions of $-\Delta u=0$ in U and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0$ on $\partial U$ are $ u \equiv C $ for some constant C.

I know that u attains max and min on $\partial U$, I wonder if u is constant on $\partial U$, can we prove this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to do this with the maximum principle, but I can give a short proof with integration by parts. On the one hand

$$-\int_U u \Delta u dx = 0$$

On the other hand

$$-\int_U u \Delta u dx = \int_U |\nabla u|^2 dx - \int_{\partial U} u \frac{du}{d \nu} dS = \int_U |\nabla u|^2 dx.$$

Hence $\nabla u = 0$ and $u \equiv C$.

Perhaps you can adapt this proof?

Comment: You are right, this can be down with integration by parts. Actually this problem is from Evans' PDE book, I have a question that, if we have $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0$ and u is smooth, can we say u is constant on $\partial U$ ?

Comment: @BingHan No: the gradient on the boundary could have a nonzero tangential component.

Comment: Oh...It seems we have to find other ways to solve this problem.....